# C adding extra spaces in trimming

Tags: c, substring

I call below function which is written in C to fetch parent of child-

```
char *getParent(char *child)
{
    int len = strlen(child);
    char *parent;
    parent = strdup(substring(child, 0, len - 4));

    return parent;

}

char *substring(const char* str, int beg, int n)
{
    char *ret = malloc(n+1);
    strncpy(ret, (str + beg), n);
    *(ret+n) = '\n';

    return strdup(ret);
}
```

child is - '11112222'
Now I am expecting output - '1111' but this function also adding extra spaces after 1111 like this  '1111---here i am getting space----'.
What's wrong in this function ?

Comment: Is `substring` a function you programmed or part of a library?

Comment: @CyrilFougeray No, `strlen()` most certainly does not include the terminator, it's not part of the string's length. `strlen("")` is 0.

Comment: `*(ret+n) = '\n';`does add a newline. You need to add a 0: `*(ret+n) = '\0';`

Comment: Sorry, now substring function added in question.

Comment: `*(ret+n) = '\n'` should probably be `ret[n] = '\0'`, also don't use `strdup` if your already using malloc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
*(ret+n) = '\n';
```

is wrong, it should be:

```
*(ret+n) = '\0';
```

to terminate the string. You're adding a linefeed, not a terminator, thus failing to produce a valid string.

Also, I would recommend prefering indexing since it's a bit cleaner syntactically:

```
ret[n] = '\0';
```

And, of course, you should check the return value of `malloc()` before relying on it.

**UPDATE**: And gosh, remove that `strdup()`, it's completely pointless now that you've already `malloc()`ed your new string.

It should be just:

```
char * substring(const char *str, size_t beg, size_t n)
{
    char *ret = malloc(n + 1);
    if(ret != NULL)
    {
        strncpy(ret, str + beg, n);
        ret[n] = '\0';
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This still assumes that the offset and length are valid, and that `str` is non-`NULL`.

Comment: @sidd: not quite, it leaks, `strdup` is unnecessary.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Gaah, completely missed that, thanks!